# Is there an analogy of the Fourier-decomposition in the Laplace space to decompose a signal to a few components?

Tags: fourier-series, laplace-transform, decomposition

I have a signal from which I know, that it is the sum of a few, exponentially decaying components. I want to find these components.

If it would be a sum of some sinusiod waves, it would be easy to Fourier-transform it, and then find the [Kronecker-deltas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) with some heuristics. It is because the Fourier-transform of a sinusiodal signal is a $\delta$.

If the signal would be the superposition of some dampened oscillators, as it is asked in [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/49057/17850), the problem would be still easily solvable by a 2d fourier transform. If I understand it well, the trick is that we use the fourier space to decompose the decaying signals. I think it would work only if the oscillators would have a different decay time constant, if they belong to different frequencies.

<sub>**However, my signal is not from dampened oscillators, it is a simple decaying signal without any oscillation, making this question not a dupe.**</sub>

My first naive try was to Laplace-transform it, and then do like in the Fourier case. It does not work, because $\mathbb L \{ae^{-bt}\}=\frac{a}{s-b}$. First, it is singular, making its digital processing problematic, but the major problem is that I can't see any easy way to find the components in the result.

Maybe Laplace is not usable for that, or it should be done with Laplace, but somehow differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover frequency and damping coefficient from superposition of damped oscillators?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49057/how-to-recover-frequency-and-damping-coefficient-from-superposition-of-damped-os)

Comment: You might find [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49057/how-to-recover-frequency-and-damping-coefficient-from-superposition-of-damped-os) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prony%27s_method) useful.

Comment: @A_A Thanks! Your first link is not usable in my case (fourier is meaningless or at least impractical for such an aperiodic signal), but your second (Prony's method) looks very interesting. I am currently trying to understand it.

Comment: @A_A My next naive idea: I would create its Taylor-series, transfer into imaginary by substituting $x \rightarrow ix$ in it, then I get a complex signal, and then I try to somehow use some duality between Fourier and Laplace. But this looks to me a quite weird idea yet. Even if it works in theory, it will probably be unusable numerically due to instabilities.

Comment: Yet another idea: Laplace-transforming the signal, and then trying a least-square approximation of it with a $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{s-b_k}$. It would result probably huge formulas, but with luck it will be not much harder than the polynomial regression. Doing the same with exponentials would be non-analytical.

Comment: Can you post a signal that is representative of what you are dealing with?

Comment: @A_A For example: $2e^{-3t}+3e^{-5t}$. I have this as measurement data (imagine as if it would come from an A/D converter). It has also noise, different errors, and so on. It is a subset of the problem what Prony's method solves, here we have $0$ on all $\omega$ tag (i.e. Prony's problem, but only from non-oscillating components).

Comment: First of all, I am sorry that I misread your original question and suggested that it has a duplicate when you have specified exactly that you are NOT looking for damped sinusoids. I lost the negation somewhere in there. Secondly, what you are dealing with (then) is plain simple model fitting. In this case, you might find [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54419/compute-time-constant-of-discrete-exponential-decay-pulses) and [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47934/how-to-extract-features-of-individual-spikes-in-non-negative-signal/47946#47946) helpful...

Comment: ...since we are dealing with model fitting, is there anything more that you can write about the nature of these decays? Are they pulses? Is there a fastest/slowest rate they can occur? Do you have the complete "pulse"? Where are these measurements coming from? What is the signal?

Comment: @A_A No, there are no pulses in it. If there would be, I would filter them out in preprocessing, but the system doesn't work so. I know from the process generating it, that it generates the sum of multiple exponential decays. I don't have the complete signal, but I have far enough to assume that appending the signal with infinite zeros probably won't cause a problem. (Here on "pulse" I understood a function looking $\delta_(t-x)$).

Comment: @A_A My current best idea: I Laplace-transform it numerically, then I try to approximate it with a polynom-quotient, then I convert this polynom-quotient to a sum of $\frac{b}{s-a}$.

Comment: @A_A Well, and yet another important thing: **having 3 exponentials will be surely enough, with luck even 2!**