# Feature extraction for exponentially damped signals

Tags: signal-analysis, python, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I am looking into exponentially damped signals where it is a stationary signal (after implementing the Adfuller statistical test) and I would like to look into how can I extract meaningful features out of the signal in order to do pattern recognition with machine learning. Can anyone guide me on where I can find articles/blogs of signal processing techniques and feature extraction of exponentially damped signal?

Comment: Can you share a bit more information about the problem? Specifically, what sort of "features" of the exponential signal are you after? E.g. amplitude, rate of decay of each sinusoid? Something else?)

Comment: @A_A relating to damping of the signal, what kind of feautres can I extract from it

Comment: If its a sinusoid damped by an exponential, you can extract the frequency of the sinusoid by taking the peak of the fft and then use it to calculate the damping factor.

Comment: @DSPNovice Thank you for your input. Well, for my situation, I already looked at it in the frequency domain and I found out that from my datasets (considering the first 3 Natural frequencies/modes) the peaks are almost the same (there's like the same deviation by only like [+] or [-] 0.5 from freq. values). Looking into the damping factor, I found out that only the second damping ratio was different but still small deviation around the same ([+] or [-] 0.5). So, I thought that it would be difficult for machine learning to identify difference between cases.

Comment: @DSPNovice So, if I still want to look into damping factors, what other features I could look into? One of my ideas is to look into energy dissipation as it might be related to damping, but I don't know how to approach it or from which domain I need to go in order to get the features. Also, in regards to signal to process, I am also a bit new into it and say a person has a signal and would like to extract features from it, what steps or points that I should know in order to implement signal processing? (As I am using Python)

Comment: Cross-correlation is usually used to get similarity between two signals. You can take your desired signal and cross-correlate with measured signal to check for similarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover frequency and damping coefficient from superposition of damped oscillators?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49057/how-to-recover-frequency-and-damping-coefficient-from-superposition-of-damped-os)

Comment: @DSPNovice If I am looking into Time-Frequency Domain, How can I extract features from damped signals?

Comment: @A_A Well, for my case, the signal I got it from an online dataset. So, I wouldn't know about the function wherein the question the user used to optimize curve_fit. Also, I have this question (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/65993/how-to-approach-feature-extraction-and-feature-selection-part-in-machone-learnin) if you both have the time can you have a look?

Comment: Also, side question when I used signaltonoise function online (python) in order to see the signal-to-noise ratio and I got a positive SNR. However, if I pass the signal into, for example, a band-pass filter to concentrate on a certain frequency band I get a negative SNR. Why is that?

Comment: @Lenman147 STFT is used to extract information in time-frequency domain

Comment: @DSPNovice Well, how can I extract features from STFT? And I also know about wavelet and HHT, what are the uses of both algorithms and how to also extract features from it?